Linear condition between two continuous variables
There are two real variables $x$ and $y$. The conditions are such that:

if $y\le 0$, then $x=0$
if $y>0$, then $x=y$

How to write linear equations or inequalities to satisfy both the conditions?

Note this is also sometimes noted $x = y^+$ or $x = \max(0, y)$, and outloud "x is the positive part of y"

Let $L_x,U_x$ denote a lower and upper bound for $x$, and  $L_y,U_y$ denote a lower and upper bound for $y$.
Define an additional binary variable $\delta \in \{0,1\}$ and enforce the following:
$$
y \le 0 \implies \delta = 1 \implies x=0 \tag{1}
$$
$$
y> 0 \implies \delta = 0 \implies x=y \tag{2}
$$
Or equivalently via contrapositive:
$$
\delta = 0 \implies x=y  \quad \text{and} \quad y> 0  \tag{3}
$$
$$
\delta = 1 \implies x=0  \quad \text{and} \quad y\le 0  \tag{4}
$$
$(3)$ can be modeled as follows:
\begin{align}
y+L_x\cdot\delta&\le x\le y+U_x\cdot\delta \tag{5}\\
\epsilon+L_y\cdot \delta &\le y \tag{6}
\end{align}
$\epsilon$ is a small positive constant (tolerance).
And $(4)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
0+L_x\cdot(1-\delta)\le x&\le 0+ U_x\cdot(1-\delta) \tag{7}\\ 
y&\le 0+U_y \cdot(1-\delta) \tag{8} 
\end{align}
As per RobPratt's comments:

$\epsilon$ can be set to $0$ (or omitted) as $(0,0)$ is a breakpoint
$L_x=0$ ; $L_y=:L$
$U_x=U_y=:U$
$(8)$ is redundant with $(5)$ and $(7)$

These simplifications yield:
\begin{align}
L\cdot \delta &\le y \\
y&\le x \\
x&\le y+U\cdot\delta \\
x&\le U\cdot(1-\delta) \\ 
x&\ge 0
\end{align}

You did not define $\epsilon$, but you can omit it here because $(0,0)$ is a breakpoint.

You can simplify further by noting that $L_x=0$ and $U_x=U_y$.

You have some sign errors for $L_x$ and $L_y$, and the constraints that involve $y$ but not $x$ are linear combinations of the other constraints.

Thanks @RobPratt for the useful comments.

Glad to help.  Looks better now, but you can strengthen $x \le y + U \cdot \delta$ to $x \le y - L \cdot \delta$.

It is worth noting that the desired relationship can be expressed as $x=\max(y,0)$.
You want to model a disjunction of two rays from the origin.  Impose finite bounds
\begin{align}
0 \le x \le U \tag1\\
L \le y \le U \tag2
\end{align}
and model a disjunction of two line segments (from $(0,0)$ to $(U,U)$ and from $(0,0)$ to $(0,L)$).  For both, we must have
$$y \le x \tag3$$
Now introduce a binary decision variable $\delta$ and enforce
\begin{align}
\delta = 0 &\implies y \ge x\\
\delta = 1 &\implies x \le 0
\end{align}
either by using indicator constraints or by explicitly imposing big-M constraints
\begin{align}
x - y &\le -L\delta \tag4\\
x &\le U(1-\delta) \tag5
\end{align}

For some models, it suffices to require $x \geq {\rm max}(y,0)$, which is easily linearized as $x \geq y$, $x \geq 0$. But if also $x \leq {\rm max}(y,0)$ must be enforced explicitly, then the binary $\delta$ must be introduced.
